# React Native StackOverflowException

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, exception, stack-overflow

I'm having the following exception in my react-native app on Android

```
E/unknown:ReactNative: Exception in native call
    com.facebook.react.uimanager.IllegalViewOperationException: StackOverflowException
        at com.facebook.react.ReactRootView.handleException(ReactRootView.java:563)
        at com.facebook.react.views.view.ReactViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ReactViewGroup.java:669)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14468)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13362)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14182)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
        at com.facebook.react.views.view.ReactViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ReactViewGroup.java:663)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14468)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13362)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14182)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
        at com.facebook.react.views.view.ReactViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ReactViewGroup.java:663)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13357)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14182)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
        at com.facebook.react.views.view.ReactViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ReactViewGroup.java:663)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13357)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14182)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
        at com.facebook.react.views.view.ReactViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ReactViewGroup.java:663)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13357)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14182)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14468)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:472)
        at android.widget.ScrollView.draw(ScrollView.java:1603)
        at com.facebook.react.views.scroll.ReactScrollView.draw(ReactScrollView.java:354)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13362)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14182)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
        at com.facebook.react.views.view.ReactViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ReactViewGroup.java:663)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14468)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13362)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14182)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
        at com.facebook.react.views.view.ReactViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ReactViewGroup.java:663)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14468)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13362)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14182)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13357)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14182)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14468)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:472)
        at android.widget.HorizontalScrollView.draw(HorizontalScrollView.java:1609)
        at com.facebook.react.views.scroll.ReactHorizontalScrollView.draw(ReactHorizontalScrollView.java:275)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13362)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
        at android.v
```

I have the following versions in my React-Native app:

- react-native: 0.55.3
- react: 16.3.1
- Android: 4.4.2

The main problem is that, this exception does not have a certain case, it just happens anywhere in the app. For example, while you've been in the app for a while, and then try to go to a screen, it crashes with this exception.

I have searched a lot about `IllegalViewOperationException`.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13984 -> The issue here suggest to remove `LayoutAnimation` however I've totally removed it from my project and I'm still facing the issue.

[com.facebook.react.uimanager.IllegalViewOperationException: Trying to add unknown view tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45002568/com-facebook-react-uimanager-illegalviewoperationexception-trying-to-add-unknow) -> the exception here seems to be caused by another reason, in my case I don't have an unknown view tag issue

I have searched a lot about `StackOverflowException` in react-native, but even in it's GitHub issues, there are zero results.

I've also checked `Exception in native call` error. For example, in this link, [E/unknown:React: Exception in native call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48352667/e-unknownreact-exception-in-native-call), the issue is caused by bundling. However my case is not related to bundling. I can successfully run the app in the emulator and navigate among screens. The exception also occurs in release mode on real devices too.

I'm unable to find an answer including `Exception in native call`, `IllegalViewOperationException`, and `StackOverflowException` keywords. The exception occurs on Android devices with only 4.x version. It does not occur on 5 and higher Android versions. I guess that it might be related to device's insufficient RAM, or the device might not handle too many renderings in consecutive page navigations. Any ideas on how I can prevent this exception?

Comment: I exactly have this issue too, did your problem solved??

Comment: I am seeing this `IllegalViewOperationException` stack overflow issue as well. I checked my `adb logcat` log for relevent lines and found [this](https://gist.github.com/Ashoat/2ac198ae97001b33c70001392b06b1b1). "stack overflow on call to Landroid/text/SpanSet"

Comment: Hi, did you managed to resolve this issue?

Comment: Stackoverflowexception means the stack is full - too many function calls can consume the stack. Check the call graph and see if there's some function which is called too many times.

Answer (score 0):

Likely you have a recursive operation forcing re-renders.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/ReactRootView.java

```
  @Override
  protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    try {
      super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
    } catch (StackOverflowError e) {
      // Adding special exception management for StackOverflowError for logging purposes.
      // This will be removed in the future.
      handleException(e);
    }
  }
```

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/view/ViewGroup.java

the `dispatchDraw` method is part of the android SDK. Is the part of the view system that allows to draw other views inside a viewGroup (a root component). By the very nature of the process (because a ViewGroup is also a View, you can nest infinite view trees inside the root), a StackoverflowException (VM ran out of memory space to place another call) is possible. React-Native relies on a custom view component, ReactRootView, which throws the exception you see if an infinite/way too expensive view tree is rendered. The structure of an RN app is an android activity, with a ReactRootView (framelayout subclass), which houses everything you add in JS. Every screen. So if one of your screen rendered way too many times & you render another, you get to the point where the ReactRootView overflows the memory stack & presto, exception.

You see this on older phones either because the device specs are below the stress your render process exerts over it, or because a particular bug on the view-generation code of RN is exposed on 4.4.2.

Try render-evaluation tools like why-did-you-render to detect unwanted rendering cycles. Otherwise you need to slim down the amount of renders.